# ssh-copy-id syntax

Tags: ssh

Lets assume that the password over ssh on a server is disabled and I have private key in file "old_key.pem" for which server already has the public key.

Now I've generated a new pair of keys say "new_key.pub" and "new_key.pem" and I want to send this .pub key to server by using "old_key.pem" and not the password. Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

The problem that I'm facing is that the `-i` parameter is used by "new_key.pub" and now I cannot use "old_key.pem" to authenticate myself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ssh-copy-id` if you already have a working public key.  Do something like this instead:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/old_key user@example.com 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/new_key.pub
```

Answer (score 0):

From how I read the docs, if you use `ssh-agent`, `ssh-copy-id` will install all keys in there that don't already work, so this ought to work (but I haven't tested it):

```
# spawn a new agent for this so we know it's not keeping keys
$(ssh-agent)
# add keys
ssh-add new-key.pem old-key.pem
# check if those keys made it in
ssh-add -l
# and now add extra keys
ssh-copy-id user@remote
# stop the extra ssh-agent
kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
```